# Problem running multiple scripts from Greasemonkey4IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, greasemonkey

```
//================MyJs.js=========================
var objGreeting = {
   Greetings : function() {
   toolbardiv = document.createElement('toolbardiv'); // create div tag dynamically
   toolbardiv.setAttribute('id',"toolbar"); // give id to it
   toolbardiv.className="top"; // set the style classname

  //set the inner styling of the div tag
   toolbardiv.style.position="absolute";

   //set the html content inside the div tag
   toolbardiv.innerHTML="<input id='Greeting-Button' type='button' value='Login'           onClick='objHello.SayHello()'/>"
   }
},

var objHello = {

   SayHello: function() {
   alert("Hello World");
   }
};
```

Right now this all is in a single JS file and it's working fine.

Now I want to separate the two classes above into two different js files.
But after doing this I am not able to call the `SayHello` method.

I am using "GreaseMonkey for IE" and IE8 to run this script.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't split files that way.   You could probably make external JS files and load them by having your script create JS `script` nodes in the document.

Comment: The code posted above is fully functional.
But I want to do it the way you are suggesting i.e,  make external JS files and load them by having your script create JS script nodes in the document.
Don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have your script insert JS dynamically, you can use something like the following:

```
function addJS_Node (text, s_URL)
{
    var scriptNode                      = document.createElement ('script');
    scriptNode.type                     = "text/javascript";

    if (text)  scriptNode.textContent   = text;
    if (s_URL) scriptNode.src           = s_URL;

    document.head.appendChild (scriptNode);
}

addJS_Node (null, 'YourPath/YourJS_File.js');
```

Note that I don't use IE, so code is untested on that platform but should work.

Depending on the web page, `document.body.appendChild` may work better.